# Pyinstaller post compilation permission error on windows 10

Tags: python, flask, pyinstaller

I've been trying to compile a Flask app using Pyinstaller for distribution. The result of the compilation says that it completed successfully but when I go to run the application I get a permission error (every time)

This is the contents of the spec file.

```
# -*- mode: python ; coding: utf-8 -*-


block_cipher = None


a = Analysis(['app.py'],
         pathex=['C:\\Users\\Kris2\\Documents\\Projects\\photos'],
         binaries=[],
         datas=[('app/static', 'app/static'), ('app/admin/static', 'app/admin/static'), ('app/client/static', 'app/client/static'), ('app/admin/templates', 'app/admin/templates'), ('app/client/templates', 'app/client/templates'), ('app/app.db', 'app/app.db')],
         hiddenimports=[],
         hookspath=[],
         hooksconfig={},
         runtime_hooks=[],
         excludes=[],
         win_no_prefer_redirects=False,
         win_private_assemblies=False,
         cipher=block_cipher,
         noarchive=False)
pyz = PYZ(a.pure, a.zipped_data,
         cipher=block_cipher)

exe = EXE(pyz,
      a.scripts, 
      [],
      exclude_binaries=True,
      name='app',
      debug=False,
      bootloader_ignore_signals=False,
      strip=False,
      upx=True,
      console=False,
      target_arch=None,
      codesign_identity=None,
      entitlements_file=None )
coll = COLLECT(exe,
           a.binaries,
           a.zipfiles,
           a.datas, 
           strip=False,
           upx=True,
           upx_exclude=[],
           name='app')
```

This is the result of the compilation.

```
(venv) C:\Users\Kris2\Documents\Projects\photos>pyinstaller -w --add-data "app/static;app/static" --add-data "app/admin/static;app/admin/static" --add-data "app/client/static;app/client/static" --add-data "app/admin/templates;app/admin/templates" --add-data "app/client/templates;app/client/templates" --add-data "app/app.db;app/app.db" app.py
234 INFO: PyInstaller: 5.0.dev0
234 INFO: Python: 3.9.5
258 INFO: Platform: Windows-10-10.0.19042-SP0
260 INFO: wrote C:\Users\Kris2\Documents\Projects\photos\app.spec
1597 INFO: UPX is available.
1619 INFO: Extending PYTHONPATH with paths
['C:\\Users\\Kris2\\Documents\\Projects\\photos',
'C:\\Users\\Kris2\\Documents\\Projects\\photos']
1960 INFO: checking Analysis
1961 INFO: Building Analysis because Analysis-00.toc is non existent
1963 INFO: Initializing module dependency graph...
1969 INFO: Caching module graph hooks...
1997 WARNING: Several hooks defined for module 'win32ctypes.core'. Please take care they do not conflict.
2045 INFO: Analyzing base_library.zip ...
9606 INFO: Processing pre-find module path hook distutils from 
'c:\\users\\kris2\\appdata\\local\\programs\\python\\python39\\lib\\site-packages\\PyInstaller\\hooks\\pre_find_module_path\\hook-distutils.py'.
9610 INFO: distutils: retargeting to non-venv dir 'c:\\users\\kris2\\appdata\\local\\programs\\python\\python39\\lib'
21619 INFO: Caching module dependency graph...
22020 INFO: running Analysis Analysis-00.toc
22050 INFO: Adding Microsoft.Windows.Common-Controls to dependent assemblies of final executable required by c:\users\kris2\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\python.exe
22523 WARNING: lib not found: api-ms-win-core-path-l1-1-0.dll dependency of c:\users\kris2\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\python39.dll
22977 INFO: Analyzing C:\Users\Kris2\Documents\Projects\photos\app.py
27815 INFO: Processing pre-find module path hook site from 'c:\\users\\kris2\\appdata\\local\\programs\\python\\python39\\lib\\site-packages\\PyInstaller\\hooks\\pre_find_module_path\\hook-site.py'.
27818 INFO: site: retargeting to fake-dir 'c:\\users\\kris2\\appdata\\local\\programs\\python\\python39\\lib\\site-packages\\PyInstaller\\fake-modules'
47328 INFO: Processing module hooks...
47329 INFO: Loading module hook 'hook-dns.rdata.py' from 'c:\\users\\kris2\\appdata\\local\\programs\\python\\python39\\lib\\site-packages\\_pyinstaller_hooks_contrib\\hooks\\stdhooks'...
48636 INFO: Loading module hook 'hook-jinja2.py' from 'c:\\users\\kris2\\appdata\\local\\programs\\python\\python39\\lib\\site-packages\\_pyinstaller_hooks_contrib\\hooks\\stdhooks'...
48638 INFO: Loading module hook 'hook-pycparser.py' from 'c:\\users\\kris2\\appdata\\local\\programs\\python\\python39\\lib\\site-packages\\_pyinstaller_hooks_contrib\\hooks\\stdhooks'...
48639 INFO: Loading module hook 'hook-win32ctypes.core.py' from 'c:\\users\\kris2\\appdata\\local\\programs\\python\\python39\\lib\\site-packages\\_pyinstaller_hooks_contrib\\hooks\\stdhooks'...
48865 INFO: Loading module hook 'hook-difflib.py' from 'c:\\users\\kris2\\appdata\\local\\programs\\python\\python39\\lib\\site-packages\\PyInstaller\\hooks'...
48869 INFO: Loading module hook 'hook-distutils.py' from 'c:\\users\\kris2\\appdata\\local\\programs\\python\\python39\\lib\\site-packages\\PyInstaller\\hooks'...
48870 INFO: Loading module hook 'hook-distutils.util.py' from 'c:\\users\\kris2\\appdata\\local\\programs\\python\\python39\\lib\\site-packages\\PyInstaller\\hooks'...
48884 INFO: Loading module hook 'hook-encodings.py' from 'c:\\users\\kris2\\appdata\\local\\programs\\python\\python39\\lib\\site-packages\\PyInstaller\\hooks'...
48959 INFO: Loading module hook 'hook-gevent.py' from 'c:\\users\\kris2\\appdata\\local\\programs\\python\\python39\\lib\\site-packages\\PyInstaller\\hooks'...
49545 INFO: Determining a mapping of distributions to packages...
56452 WARNING: Unable to find package for requirement zope.interface from package gevent.
56452 WARNING: Unable to find package for requirement zope.event from package gevent.
56453 INFO: Packages required by gevent:['cffi', 'setuptools', 'greenlet']
59915 INFO: Loading module hook 'hook-heapq.py' from 'c:\\users\\kris2\\appdata\\local\\programs\\python\\python39\\lib\\site-packages\\PyInstaller\\hooks'...
59925 INFO: Loading module hook 'hook-lib2to3.py' from 'c:\\users\\kris2\\appdata\\local\\programs\\python\\python39\\lib\\site-packages\\PyInstaller\\hooks'...
60019 INFO: Loading module hook 'hook-multiprocessing.util.py' from 'c:\\users\\kris2\\appdata\\local\\programs\\python\\python39\\lib\\site-packages\\PyInstaller\\hooks'...
60027 INFO: Loading module hook 'hook-pickle.py' from 'c:\\users\\kris2\\appdata\\local\\programs\\python\\python39\\lib\\site-packages\\PyInstaller\\hooks'...
60035 INFO: Loading module hook 'hook-PIL.Image.py' from 'c:\\users\\kris2\\appdata\\local\\programs\\python\\python39\\lib\\site-packages\\PyInstaller\\hooks'...
61333 INFO: Loading module hook 'hook-PIL.ImageFilter.py' from 'c:\\users\\kris2\\appdata\\local\\programs\\python\\python39\\lib\\site-packages\\PyInstaller\\hooks'...
61343 INFO: Loading module hook 'hook-PIL.py' from 'c:\\users\\kris2\\appdata\\local\\programs\\python\\python39\\lib\\site-packages\\PyInstaller\\hooks'...
61361 INFO: Loading module hook 'hook-PIL.SpiderImagePlugin.py' from 'c:\\users\\kris2\\appdata\\local\\programs\\python\\python39\\lib\\site-packages\\PyInstaller\\hooks'...
61369 INFO: Loading module hook 'hook-pkg_resources.py' from 'c:\\users\\kris2\\appdata\\local\\programs\\python\\python39\\lib\\site-packages\\PyInstaller\\hooks'...
61978 INFO: Processing pre-safe import module hook win32com from 'c:\\users\\kris2\\appdata\\local\\programs\\python\\python39\\lib\\site-packages\\_pyinstaller_hooks_contrib\\hooks\\pre_safe_import_module\\hook-win32com.py'.
62985 WARNING: Hidden import "pkg_resources.py2_warn" not found!
62986 WARNING: Hidden import "pkg_resources.markers" not found!
62995 INFO: Loading module hook 'hook-setuptools.py' from 'c:\\users\\kris2\\appdata\\local\\programs\\python\\python39\\lib\\site-packages\\PyInstaller\\hooks'...
64531 INFO: Import to be excluded not found: 'setuptools.py33compat'
64532 INFO: Import to be excluded not found: 'setuptools.py27compat'
64534 INFO: Loading module hook 'hook-sqlalchemy.py' from 'c:\\users\\kris2\\appdata\\local\\programs\\python\\python39\\lib\\site-packages\\PyInstaller\\hooks'...
65460 WARNING: Hidden import "pysqlite2" not found!
65462 WARNING: Hidden import "MySQLdb" not found!
65465 WARNING: Hidden import "psycopg2" not found!
68402 INFO: Loading module hook 'hook-sqlite3.py' from 'c:\\users\\kris2\\appdata\\local\\programs\\python\\python39\\lib\\site-packages\\PyInstaller\\hooks'...
68635 INFO: Loading module hook 'hook-sysconfig.py' from 'c:\\users\\kris2\\appdata\\local\\programs\\python\\python39\\lib\\site-packages\\PyInstaller\\hooks'...
68636 INFO: Loading module hook 'hook-xml.dom.domreg.py' from 'c:\\users\\kris2\\appdata\\local\\programs\\python\\python39\\lib\\site-packages\\PyInstaller\\hooks'...
68641 INFO: Loading module hook 'hook-xml.etree.cElementTree.py' from 'c:\\users\\kris2\\appdata\\local\\programs\\python\\python39\\lib\\site-packages\\PyInstaller\\hooks'...
68643 INFO: Loading module hook 'hook-xml.py' from 'c:\\users\\kris2\\appdata\\local\\programs\\python\\python39\\lib\\site-packages\\PyInstaller\\hooks'...
68646 INFO: Loading module hook 'hook-zope.interface.py' from 'c:\\users\\kris2\\appdata\\local\\programs\\python\\python39\\lib\\site-packages\\PyInstaller\\hooks'...
68654 INFO: Loading module hook 'hook-_tkinter.py' from 'c:\\users\\kris2\\appdata\\local\\programs\\python\\python39\\lib\\site-packages\\PyInstaller\\hooks'...
69055 INFO: checking Tree
69056 INFO: Building Tree because Tree-00.toc is non existent
69058 INFO: Building Tree Tree-00.toc
69188 INFO: checking Tree
69188 INFO: Building Tree because Tree-01.toc is non existent
69195 INFO: Building Tree Tree-01.toc
69428 INFO: checking Tree
69429 INFO: Building Tree because Tree-02.toc is non existent
69432 INFO: Building Tree Tree-02.toc
69446 INFO: Loading module hook 'hook-pythoncom.py' from 'c:\\users\\kris2\\appdata\\local\\programs\\python\\python39\\lib\\site-packages\\_pyinstaller_hooks_contrib\\hooks\\stdhooks'...
70327 INFO: Loading module hook 'hook-pywintypes.py' from 'c:\\users\\kris2\\appdata\\local\\programs\\python\\python39\\lib\\site-packages\\_pyinstaller_hooks_contrib\\hooks\\stdhooks'...
71173 INFO: Loading module hook 'hook-win32com.py' from 'c:\\users\\kris2\\appdata\\local\\programs\\python\\python39\\lib\\site-packages\\_pyinstaller_hooks_contrib\\hooks\\stdhooks'...
72435 INFO: Loading module hook 'hook-setuptools.msvc.py' from 'c:\\users\\kris2\\appdata\\local\\programs\\python\\python39\\lib\\site-packages\\PyInstaller\\hooks'...
72576 INFO: Looking for ctypes DLLs
72597 WARNING: library ApplicationServices required via ctypes not found
72734 INFO: Analyzing run-time hooks ...
72749 INFO: Including run-time hook 'c:\\users\\kris2\\appdata\\local\\programs\\python\\python39\\lib\\site-packages\\PyInstaller\\hooks\\rthooks\\pyi_rth_multiprocessing.py'
72773 INFO: Including run-time hook 'c:\\users\\kris2\\appdata\\local\\programs\\python\\python39\\lib\\site-packages\\PyInstaller\\hooks\\rthooks\\pyi_rth_win32api.py'
72793 INFO: Including run-time hook 'c:\\users\\kris2\\appdata\\local\\programs\\python\\python39\\lib\\site-packages\\PyInstaller\\hooks\\rthooks\\pyi_rth_pkgres.py'
72823 INFO: Including run-time hook 'c:\\users\\kris2\\appdata\\local\\programs\\python\\python39\\lib\\site-packages\\PyInstaller\\hooks\\rthooks\\pyi_rth_win32comgenpy.py'
72875 INFO: Looking for dynamic libraries
74314 INFO: Looking for eggs
74315 INFO: Using Python library c:\users\kris2\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\python39.dll
74316 INFO: Found binding redirects:[]
74335 INFO: Warnings written to C:\Users\Kris2\Documents\Projects\photos\build\app\warn-app.txt
74840 INFO: Graph cross-reference written to C:\Users\Kris2\Documents\Projects\photos\build\app\xref-app.html
74923 INFO: Appending 'datas' from .spec
74989 INFO: checking PYZ
74990 INFO: Building PYZ because PYZ-00.toc is non existent
74993 INFO: Building PYZ (ZlibArchive) C:\Users\Kris2\Documents\Projects\photos\build\app\PYZ-00.pyz
79158 INFO: Building PYZ (ZlibArchive) C:\Users\Kris2\Documents\Projects\photos\build\app\PYZ-00.pyz completed successfully.
79264 INFO: checking PKG
79265 INFO: Building PKG because PKG-00.toc is non existent
79267 INFO: Building PKG (CArchive) PKG-00.pkg
79379 INFO: Building PKG (CArchive) PKG-00.pkg completed successfully.
79382 INFO: Bootloader c:\users\<name>\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\bootloader\Windows-64bit\runw.exe
79383 INFO: checking EXE
79384 INFO: Building EXE because EXE-00.toc is non existent
79385 INFO: Building EXE from EXE-00.toc
79513 INFO: Copying icons from ['c:\\users\\<name>\\appdata\\local\\programs\\python\\python39\\lib\\site-packages\\PyInstaller\\bootloader\\images\\icon-windowed.ico']
79645 INFO: Writing RT_GROUP_ICON 0 resource with 104 bytes
79645 INFO: Writing RT_ICON 1 resource with 3752 bytes
79647 INFO: Writing RT_ICON 2 resource with 2216 bytes
79660 INFO: Writing RT_ICON 3 resource with 1384 bytes
79661 INFO: Writing RT_ICON 4 resource with 38188 bytes
79662 INFO: Writing RT_ICON 5 resource with 9640 bytes
79664 INFO: Writing RT_ICON 6 resource with 4264 bytes
79665 INFO: Writing RT_ICON 7 resource with 1128 bytes
79683 INFO: Appending archive to EXE C:\Users\<name>\Documents\Projects\photos\build\app\app.exe
83128 INFO: Building EXE from EXE-00.toc completed successfully.
83148 INFO: checking COLLECT
83149 INFO: Building COLLECT because COLLECT-00.toc is non existent
83154 INFO: Building COLLECT COLLECT-00.toc
89684 INFO: Building COLLECT COLLECT-00.toc completed successfully.
```

This is the errors when I try to run it.

```
(venv) C:\Users\Kris2\Documents\Projects\photos\dist>pyinstaller app /
230 INFO: PyInstaller: 5.0.dev0
230 INFO: Python: 3.9.5
248 INFO: Platform: Windows-10-10.0.19042-SP0
250 INFO: wrote C:\Users\Kris2\Documents\Projects\photos\dist\app.spec
373 INFO: UPX is available.
398 INFO: Extending PYTHONPATH with paths
['C:\\Users\\Kris2\\Documents\\Projects\\photos\\dist',
 'C:\\',
 'C:\\Users\\Kris2\\Documents\\Projects\\photos\\dist']
426 INFO: checking Analysis
426 INFO: Building Analysis because Analysis-00.toc is non existent
427 INFO: Initializing module dependency graph...
432 INFO: Caching module graph hooks...
453 WARNING: Several hooks defined for module 'win32ctypes.core'. Please take care they do not conflict.
463 INFO: Analyzing base_library.zip ...
5815 INFO: Processing pre-find module path hook distutils from 'c:\\users\\kris2\\appdata\\local\\programs\\python\\python39\\lib\\site-packages\\PyInstaller\\hooks\\pre_find_module_path\\hook-distutils.py'.
5817 INFO: distutils: retargeting to non-venv dir 'c:\\users\\kris2\\appdata\\local\\programs\\python\\python39\\lib'
10221 INFO: Caching module dependency graph...
10630 INFO: running Analysis Analysis-00.toc
10667 INFO: Adding Microsoft.Windows.Common-Controls to dependent assemblies of final executable required by c:\users\kris2\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\python.exe
10765 WARNING: lib not found: api-ms-win-core-path-l1-1-0.dll dependency of c:\users\kris2\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\python39.dll
11164 INFO: Analyzing C:\Users\Kris2\Documents\Projects\photos\dist\app
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\users\kris2\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\runpy.py", line 197, in _run_module_as_main
return _run_code(code, main_globals, None,
  File "c:\users\kris2\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\runpy.py", line 87, in _run_code
exec(code, run_globals)
  File "C:\Users\Kris2\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\Scripts\pyinstaller.exe\__main__.py", line 7, in <module>
  File "c:\users\kris2\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\__main__.py", line 114, in run
run_build(pyi_config, spec_file, **vars(args))
  File "c:\users\kris2\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\__main__.py", line 65, in run_build
PyInstaller.building.build_main.main(pyi_config, spec_file, **kwargs)
  File "c:\users\kris2\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\building\build_main.py", line 758, in main
build(specfile, kw.get('distpath'), kw.get('workpath'), kw.get('clean_build'))
  File "c:\users\kris2\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\building\build_main.py", line 705, in build
exec(code, spec_namespace)
  File "C:\Users\Kris2\Documents\Projects\photos\dist\app.spec", line 7, in <module>
a = Analysis(['app', '/'],
  File "c:\users\kris2\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\building\build_main.py", line 254, in __init__
self.__postinit__()
  File "c:\users\kris2\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\building\datastruct.py", line 159, in __postinit__
self.assemble()
  File "c:\users\kris2\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\building\build_main.py", line 427, in assemble
priority_scripts.append(self.graph.add_script(script))
  File "c:\users\kris2\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\depend\analysis.py", line 304, in add_script
self._top_script_node = super(PyiModuleGraph, self).add_script(
  File "c:\users\kris2\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\lib\modulegraph\modulegraph.py", line 1415, in add_script
with open(pathname, 'rb') as fp:
PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: 'C:\\Users\\Kris2\\Documents\\Projects\\photos\\dist\\app'
```

I have been trying to solve this for 2 days now and implemented all of the tweaks and commands that I have found.

Any help would be greatly appreciated, Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Based on

```
with open(pathname, 'rb') as fp:
PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: 'C:\\Users\\Kris2\\Documents\\Projects\\photos\\dist\\app'
```

PyInstaller is attempting to read `app` as if it was a file... and with your command line that's exactly what you're telling it to do.

You don't need to run your app with

```
pyinstaller app /
```

– after Pyinstaller has done its thing, you should end up with an app.exe (on Windows anyway) that you can just run.

Comment: Thanks for replying, I ran pyinstaller app to get some error output. When I try to run the executable it opens a command line and it closes before I can see anything. Either way the program doesn't run.

Comment: Run the executable from the command prompt so you can see the output; just `app.exe`?

Comment: I get a dialog box saying that it failed to execute script

Comment: Recreate the app without the `-w` option, so you do get a console, then retry.